# how do I add Url data to the existing table with rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add data for the data already exists with Ruby on Rails

**the table I want to add new data, ex:**

```
Id Name Url 
1  Tom 

2  Mike

3  Sam
```

The data existing in the table doesn't have Url data anywhere

but I want to add Url data I have now

***how do I add Url data to the existing table with using `find_by` or `where` and so on in rails console?***

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#crud-reading-and-writing-data and https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html cover everything you want to know about databases in Rails

Comment: thank you, i thought i can't get information for how to i want, but i think I can if  I use update method

Comment: `Model.find_by(name: 'Tom').update(url: 'example.com')` where `Model` is indeed the name of your model or just `Model.find(1).update...` if you want to update by primary key

Answer (score 0):

Find the record using either `record = ModelName.find(id)` or `record = ModelName.find_by(name: name)` based on the data attribute available to you and then run `record.update(url: url)` to update the URL attribute.